# How to quickly create a wix setup for a visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

I have several large websites that I wish to create a WIX installer for.  I'm dreading coming up with the initial WIX setup since there are a lot of files.  Are there any shortcuts for this?  I mean, if is there any tool I can use that I can point to a file system and tell it to generate components for every item?  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and have the WIX plugin installed, but I don't see anything that could take a project output and then generate the components.  Please let me know if something like that exists.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [WiX Heat tool](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm). It might meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [IsWiX](http://iswix.codeplex.com) ( Industrial Strength Windows Installer XML ).  The concept is you create merge module project(s) to organize your files into collections of related components and then consume them with a WiX installer project.   You can take a look at the source code to see how IsWiX uses IsWiX to create it's own installer.